# How can I log the member when they selfmute/selfdeafen/selfunmute/selfundeafen with discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So recently I'm confused that how can I log the member who updates its' voice state (Like muting/deafening themselves) into the text channel. I've made the logs when the members join/leave/move between the voice channel. But I don't know how to make voice state update about the self mute etc. Can someone tell me how can I do this, please?

Comment: Hi @Bobosky welcome to SO! Could you provide some code which you have tried so that we can support you, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the documentation there is this function:

```
voiceStateUpdate
```

it says: **Emitted whenever a member changes voice state - e.g. joins/leaves a channel, mutes/unmutes.**

and accept this parameters:

```
oldState    VoiceState  The voice state before the update
newState    VoiceState  The voice state after the update
```

You can detect this in this way:

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState,newState) => {
    if(oldState.selfMute === true && newState.selfMute === false)
        console.log("unmuted")
    if(oldState.selfMute === false && newState.selfMute === true)
        console.log("muted")
    if(oldState.selfDeaf === true && newState.selfDeaf === false)
        console.log("undeaf")
    if(oldState.selfDeaf === false && newState.selfDeaf === true)
        console.log("deaf")
});
```

Comment: How do I label who muted and unmuted? Like adding a user.tag of the member who mutes himself.

Comment: nvm I figured how to do this.